How do I recompile a MSI and change it's configurations files?
I have a MSI that installs a Zabbix Agent 2, and their documentations states that in order for us to install custom plugins we need to:
Copy the plugin into the MSI packages;
Edit configurationfiles in the MSI and point to the copied plugin path;
Their documentation don't teach how to do this. Only for Linux.
How can I do it?

You do not compile an MSI. You can edit one using something called Orca that is in the Microsoft Windows SDK. If you need to build your own MSI it can be generated with something called WiX or with a licensed application like InstallShield.
Also, MSIs are meant to only be utilized on Windows. They are not meant to run on Linux.
Please let this group know if you'd still like to move forward. There are more than enough expert Windows installer devs following this group.

I see. I need to add a folder inside it and edit a config file from it... Can I do that using Orca?

I think what you'll want is to generate either a Transform (.mst) or a Merge Module (.msm). I'll let you google merge modules and transforms
